# What does "TON" in TON 618 stand for?

Tags: quasars, naming

I don't think [TON 618](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TON_618) is a random name, but rather a composition of category name and a number.

But when I tried to google it, any article about TON 618 did not contain anything about its name origin and nor did lists about astronomy acronyms contained the term TON.

Even if I am wrong about the composition of category name with a number, I still cannot find any information about origin of its name.

So please, can anyone tell me how TON 618 got its name?

Comment: I think you could also write a follow-up question "In what ways do quasars get their designations?" See for example the answer to [How did Biden become VP? (naming of 2012 VP113)](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28773/7982) and [How official is TNO 486958, 2014 MU69's new name Arrokoth?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33916/7982) and [What is the naming convention for newly discovered objects?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/81/7982)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tonantzitla Observatory.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TON_618 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonantzintla_Observatory

Comment: Oh, thanks, I am an idiot, when I skimmed the article on wikipedia, I did not make that connection.

Comment: It’s not being an idiot; it’s a moment of lacking attention… Everyone has one of them once in a while…